# Why is my IDE complaining about new syntax after I've installed Roslyn?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2013, resharper, roslyn

I'm using `Visual Studio 2013` currently and I write this simple code:

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string error = "Hello world!");
    }
}
```

Obviously this is not a valid C# code, but the weird part is even though I see two errors, the code is compiling and working fine:

[image]

I'm thinking that migth be relevant with `Roslyn`  because I installed [`Roslyn User Preview`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/roslyn) and other extensions,but the project template I'm using is standart `Console Application` template.So, why this code is compiling even though there is three compiler errors? I tried this with `VS 2012` and it doesn't compile.Is that a compiler bug, or will this be valid in next version of `C#` ?

Here is the error list I'm seeing in `VS 2012`:

[image]

But there is definitely no error in `VS 2013`.

Note: I'm not sure whether it's relevant or not but I'm also using the `Resharper`.

Comment: Are you sure you're not executing a previous version? Clean your solution, change the string to something else and try again?

Comment: @Blorgbeard yes, I'm pretty sure.I tried this several times, I noticed that in another project and I create a new one.But still it does compile

Comment: Are you using Roslyn?

Comment: I changed the title a little to make it more descriptive. I was stuck on this for over an hour before I thankfully decided to browse some Roslyn questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In VS 2013 with Roslyn but without ReSharper, the code compiles fine and I don't see any errors or squigglies.

This is the expected behavior, since this proposed C# 6.0 feature is supported in the current Roslyn preview.

If I enable ReSharper, I start seeing the squigglies, but there are no errors in the Error List window and the code still compiles fine.

This is *also* the expected behavior, because the current version of R# doesn't have any support for C# 6.0 features (why would it?).

So, you see the squigglies from R#, but VS can work with the code just fine.

If you want to try out the proposed C# 6.0 features, I suggest you [temporarily disable R#](http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23865776-How-can-I-temporary-disable-turn-off-ReSharper-).

Answer (score 10):

Welcome to the future! These "declaration expressions" are being considered for the next version of C#, and if you're using the Roslyn preview you get to try them out early.

Comment: this doesn't explain the red squigglies (and compilation errors reported by the IDE), though

Comment: interesting ! :) I think you right, but still I don't understand why I'm seeing these errors and the redline ofcourse.. I have watched a video in Channel 9 and see some new features but I have never seen this.it seems that is another feature they didn't mention

Comment: @HighCore: The errors are being reported by VS2012, which does not use Roslyn.

Comment: @SLaks yes I don't see the error in error list in vs 2013, but I see the redline and definitely I'm seeing the error messages when I move the cursor to the redline(s)

Comment: @Selman22 Presumably VS2013 havn't been thaught the particular syntax yet. But since you compile it with roslyn, which does know about this syntax, it compiles. It could ofcourse just be a bug in roslyn/vs2013 interactions, not that surprising for a preview release.